# Git retagging sane and insane advice

Tags: git

While I was reading about renaming of git tags , many people pointed to read [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_re_tagging) :

> But if you have pushed things out (or others could just read your
> repository directly), then others will have already seen the old tag.
> In that case you can do one of two things:
>
> **The sane thing.**
>
> Just admit you screwed up, and use a different name.
> Others have already seen one tag-name, and if you keep the same name,
> you may be in the situation that two people both have "version X", but
> they actually have different "X"'s. So just call it "X.1" and be done
> with it.
>
> **The insane thing.**
>
> You really want to call the new version "X" too,
> even though others have already seen the old one. So just use git tag
> -f again, as if you hadn’t already published the old one.
>
> However, Git does not (and it should not) change tags behind users
> back. So if somebody already got the old tag, doing a git pull on your
> tree shouldn’t just make them overwrite the old one.
>
> If somebody got a release tag from you, you cannot just change the tag
> for them by updating your own one. This is a big security issue, in
> that people MUST be able to trust their tag-names. If you really want
> to do the insane thing, you need to just fess up to it, and tell
> people that you messed up.

I am not sure if I followed this completely.

**Q)** In sane thing what does he mean by -  `if you keep the same name, you may be in the situation that two people both have "version X", but they actually have different "X"'s. So just call it "X.1" and be done with it.`

In insane thing , it is written that if I keep the tag name same and force push , git pull won't update my coworkers having that old tag. Hence  what does he mean by - `you may be in the situation ....` . What can be the situation ?

Comment: Tags are meant to be immutable. If you use `tag -f` to force changing a tag you reach into troubles because nobody expects that. And because the tags are supposed to be immutable, their changes do not propagate the same way the changes of branches do. You'll end up with inconsistent tags; in different repos you'll have tags that have the same name but point to different commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a branch has the history of `A-B-C`. You make a tag `foo` on `B` and push it to the remote repository. Bob fetches the branch and gets the tag `foo` which points to `B`.

Later you find that the tag should have been on `C`. So you retag `foo` on `C` and force-push it to the remote repository but tells nobody else. Mary fetches the branch and gets the tag `foo` which poinst to `C`.

From your release note Bob and Mary get to know that the version `foo` is a stable revision so they checkout `foo` in their own repositories. If `B` and `C` happen to have the same tree which means the codes are the same, you are just lucky. However most probably they have different trees. This is the situation where Bob and Mary get different codes from `foo` and they don't know about it.

Bob may find a bug which has been fixed in `C` and tells Mary about it, but Mary tells Bob that she can't reproduce the bug. Bob says he checks out `foo`, and Mary says so does she. It may take effort that could have been avoided to find out the real reason. It gets worse when more people get the tags that have the same name but point to different commits.

Comment: So, if bob does a `git pull` , won't it get the updated tag to `C` ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Bob needs to run `git pull --tags` or `git fetch origin refs/tags/foo:refs/tags/foo` to update the local tag `foo`.

Comment: So, when he does that , where is the confusion ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin If he runs `git pull --tags`, there will be no confusion. Then the problem is how to make sure he or anyone else who has got the old tag will do so.

Comment: In 90% of these so called-insane practices, Bob and Mary figure out that they have different hashes for their repo's head, and one (or both of them) fetch and pull again, fixing the problem.  Calling it an insane practice is just dumb, if it was insane, git would prevent it.  It's just non-mainstream.